# In what scope and how should a std::random_device be defined?

Tags: c++, optimization, random, concurrency, storage-class-specifier

I want to run two concurrent threads both of which call a function (e.g. `void channel()`) and that function needs access to a few objects namely a `std::random_device`, a PRNG engine, and two `std::uniform_int_distribution` objects. However I am not sure where I should define each of these objects. 3 different options come to my mind:

1. Globally
2. Inside the `channel` function as `thread_local` (this one seems more natural to me)
3. In the body of each of thread functions (i.e. `thread1` and `thread2`) as automatic variables.

Which one is the most efficient and least problematic? And is there any other option that might be better?

Here's an MRE ([link](https://godbolt.org/z/cG1jKrMor)):

```
#include <chrono>
#include <random>
#include <thread>
#include <fmt/core.h>
#include <fmt/std.h>

using std::chrono_literals::operator""ms;

// globally defined
// extern thread_local std::random_device rand_dev;
// extern thread_local std::random_device rand_dev { };

void
channel( /*std::mt19937& mtgen*/ )
{

    // inside the function as thread_local
    thread_local std::random_device rand_dev { };
    thread_local std::mt19937 mtgen { rand_dev( ) };
    thread_local std::uniform_int_distribution uniform_50_50_dist { 1, 2 };

    if ( uniform_50_50_dist( mtgen ) == 1 )
    {
        thread_local std::uniform_int_distribution<size_t> uniform_dist_for_bit_select { 0, 10 };
        const auto random_index { uniform_dist_for_bit_select( mtgen ) };

        std::this_thread::sleep_for( 100ms );
        fmt::print( "thread: {} produced {}\n", std::this_thread::get_id( ),
                                                random_index );
    }
}

void thread1( )
{
    // inside the actual thread as automatic storage duration
    // std::random_device rand_dev { };
    // std::mt19937 mtgen { rand_dev( ) };

    for ( size_t count { }; count < 10; ++count )
    {
        channel( /*mtgen*/ );
    }
}

void thread2( )
{
    // inside the actual thread as automatic storage duration
    // std::random_device rand_dev { };
    // std::mt19937 mtgen { rand_dev( ) };

    for ( size_t count { }; count < 5; ++count )
    {
        channel( /*mtgen*/ );
    }
}

int main( )
{
    std::jthread th1 { thread1 };
    std::jthread th2 { thread2 };
}
```

Now I may have to mention that I want each thread to have a separate `std::random_device` and a separate `std::mt19937` engine so that I don't have to share them between threads (because that way I'll have to synchronize them using e.g. mutexes). Although I guess using a single `std::random_device` is possible by locking its mutex with a `std::scoped_lock` before accessing it via its `call operator()`.

Comment: Why can't each thread be more self-contained? Globals are usually **not** the answer.

Comment: @tadman So which option should I choose?

Comment: Create it in the thread and use it in the `channel()` function, easy answer. The cost of creating the device is marginal, but in a loop it would be wasteful.

Comment: @tadman So basically option 3? And also isn't a `thread_local` object similar to a `static` one in that it gets initialized only once? Do you mean the thread_local variables inside `channel()` will be constructed every time `channel` is called?

Comment: You don't need anything special, each thread function here has its own local scope, so just go with option 3.

Comment: @tadman I did a bit of tesing those 3 solutions on Compiler Explorer. The 2nd option (which uses all `thread_local` objects) produced the least lines of assembly code. I guess it's the most efficient one. And I think that it makes the code clearer and more correct. So eventually I chose the the 2nd option.

Comment: "Least lines of assembly" is not a useful metric. There are consequences to using `thread_local` beyond executable size.

Comment: @tadman Could you give me a resource on what these consequences are? I am interested in knowing about them.

Comment: The simplest, least fuss approach here is to create the necessary thread-specific generators in the thread functions themselves, those are only ever called once in your code. Then pass those in to the other function. Right now you've complicated things by introducing thread concerns into a function which shouldn't care how it's called, so long as it's called with a valid generator.

Comment: Imagine if you had a bunch of these functions which need generators. Using your `thread_local` approach you're going to have instances of these things here, there and everywhere when you only need one per thread. Keep your function focused on generating results with a *given* random generator. Let the thread entry functions focus on getting that set up correctly *once*.

Comment: @tadman Thanks, I get it now. Although I'm aiming to call that function (i.e. `channel`) from multiple threads. I will not call it from let's say the main thread. That's why I thought that the `thread_local` approach is valid (so that each thread except *main* will have its own set of random device and engine and int distribution objects). Do you think that this reasoning is acceptable?

Comment: I think the simplest approach is often the best place to start, and keeping all the `thread_local` clutter out of that function is the best plan. Give it well defined arguments. This makes it easy to test. Right now to test this with different generators, your test will have to make up a bunch of threads for no reason other than to exercise the thread-local behaviour. That shouldn't be necessary. Functions should not have internal state if it can be avoided, and `thread_local` is internal state.

Comment: @tadman Previously, I had declared those variables as `static` assuming that it will make each thread have an instance of each of those variables for itself. It worked without causing any issues. But then I realized that the `static` keyword doesn't make each thread have its own instances. And so the threads that I was calling were using the same objects to create random numbers. And as far as I know, this is called a data race condition. Is this all true? I don't even know how my program could run without having bugs.

Comment: Race conditions are things that *might* happen, not things that *will* happen. One day you might have to track down one of those that only occurs under a very specific set of extremely difficult to reproduce circumstances, and I wish you luck on that day. For now, avoiding those is best done by keeping these functions completely free of local state. You can't have race conditions if you don't share data.

Comment: @tadman Makes more sense now. Thanks. And one more little question: For now, I'm calling the `channel` function and few other functions synchronously one after the other in a while loop inside each thread. Think of it as a while true loop inside the body of each thread function that called several functions one after the other. This is how I've designed it. But I'm actually planning on turning each of those several functions into `std::jthread` objects and so each function including the `channel` can run as a separate thread. What should I do for that design?

Comment: @tadman I mean where should I define those aforementioned variables and with what storage class duration? Just automatic in the body of the `channel` or `thread_local`? or again inside the body of the calling thread and pass it as a `std::ref(mtgen)` to the channel when creating its jthread?

Comment: Outside the loop in your `thread1` type functions, where your commented-out code is presently. This creates them ones, shares them never, and doesn't clutter your inner function up with locals.